# Angular directive to handle mouse paste by cleaning string from clipboard

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm so close.

My input is a number input, with a increment=".000001" and hiding the spin buttons.

In my directive I have:

```
@HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    console.log('You have pasted successfully');
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    let clipboardData = event.clipboardData;
    let pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text').toUpperCase();
    console.log("pastedText: " + pastedText);
    let trimmedText = pastedText.replace(/\s|[A-Z_]|[#$%,^&*()]/g, '');
    console.log("trimmedText: " + trimmedText);
    (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value = trimmedText;
}
```

if I paste, with mouse right click or ctrl + v paste, the string: sd87634ee5jkbhsdf74bhgf.34iuhsdef76

event.target.value = trimmedText;
console.log("trimmedText: " + trimmedText);
trimmedText equals 87634574.3476, so the initial string is cleaned perfectly..

but when the function is completed, it appends a messier version 87634574.347687634e5743476

What's going on here?

Comment: looks like you're not actually stopping the paste event. you're just setting the value and then the paste is appending the pasted value to the value you set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to add this at the top of your function:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

to actually stop the native paste event from executing after you set the input value.

right now you're just setting a value `87634574.3476` then the paste is executing and appending the pasted value `87634e5743476` which is your pasted value without invalid number characters (yes, one e is a valid number character).

Comment: duh. Staring at this too long, lol! Thank you.